# Loop through a list of names and loop through a list of colors and bind the background color style to one of those names

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vuex, v-for

Am looping through an array of colors in my store from a Vue component, then am also looping through an array of names from same store and displaying them in a div in my component. I would like to bind each div with the name to one of the colors,
My code looks like

```
<div  
           class="names"
            v-for="user in getUsers" 
            :key="user.id">
            <div
                id='user'
                v-for="color in getColor"
                :key="color.id"
                :style="{backgroundColor:color}"
                >{{user.name[0]}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is Its showing one name for all five colors I have
For instance name james is shown in all five colors, then name susan in all five colors. I am also pulling the store data using a computed property.

```
computed: mapState({
    getUsers: state => state.users,
    getColor: state => state.colors })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one loop and use its index to get the details of the other entry based on the colors length and modulo `%` :

```
     <div
        class="names"
        v-for="(user,index) in getUsers" 
        :key="user.id">
        <div
            id='user'
            :style="{getColors[index%getColors.length]}" >
              {{user.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am going to instead of having five users ill have over 100 pulled from an API, but colors will remain the same, in such a case what would happen. At the moment its displaying as I want with the slight problem of repeating all five colors on one name, then moving to the next name and repeating all five colors again. I want it to show one name one color, when all colors are done it starts again one name one color till all names are complete

Comment: I think you should try with mod `:style="{getColors[index%getColors.length]}"`

Comment: good, please don't forget to upvote my answer